# How can you preserve the value of a pointer in c ++ without overwriting it

Tags: c++, pointers, overwrite

I Have this sandbox code for a proyect more complicated :

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Table
{
    friend class Variable;
public:
    Variable * variables[1021];
};

class Variable
{
    friend class Nodo;
public:
    char clas;
    Nodo * ini;
};

class Nodo
{   
public:
    char clas;
    Variable * father;
private:
    float * value;
public:
    Nodo();
    void set_value(float);
    float * get_value();
};


Nodo::Nodo()
{
    clas = ' ';
    father = NULL;
    value = NULL;
}

void Nodo::set_value(float m)
{
    float * r = new float();
    r = &m;
    value = (float *)r;
}

float * Nodo::get_value() 
{
    return this->value;
}
```

And this is the main:

```
void main ()
{
    Nodo * n = new Nodo();    // OK.
    n->set_value(5.3442);     // Ok. 

    Variable * v = new Variable();      // This is the problem.

    // When I declare another pointer an initilized it, n lost the value stored in value. 

    Variable * v0 = new Variable();   // Here the same.  
    v->ini = n;
    n->father = v;

    Table * t = new Table();
    t->variables[0] = v;

    v0 = t->variables[0];

    cout << *(static_cast<float *>(v0->ini->get_value())) << endl;
}
```

How can I stock the value in the pointer without change? It seems that I should use const, or something similar, but I don't know how. Declaring the field value as private doesn't help. The idea is replace value with a void * later, to store any king of basic date not only float data.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry but it is unclear to me what your problem is.  What is wrong with `Variable * v = new Variable(); `?

Comment: `void main ()` is plain wrong and I can't see a reason for that pointer business. You should read a good C++ book.

Comment: C++ is not Java. You don't need all those `new`s.

Comment: It only a test. I solve it thanks to marcinj.

Comment: Thanks Christian Hackl, I sustitute new Variable() with  &Variable()

Comment: @greatfullgigapower It looks like you're making a linked-list. Are you doing this as a learning exercise? If not, `std::vector` will probably do what you want with much less effort.

Comment: @Jack Deeth Well, Yes, it a learning exercise. The idea is create a hash table with fixed size (1021, a prime number), store variables with his name and a pointer to a Node that store the value in a void pointer. Obviusly I need to add more things to the code if I want to store arrays, detect collision in the hash table, etc. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks wrong:

```
void Nodo::set_value(float m)
{
    float * r = new float();
    r = &m;
    value = (float *)r;
}
```

`r` is assigned pointer to `m` which is a temporary, this pointer will be invalid once `set_value` finishes. Also you overwrite r value, so you have a leak here. The correct version would be:

```
void Nodo::set_value(float m)
{
    float * r = new float();
    *r = m;
    value = r;
}
```

btw. I am not digging deeper in your code, ...

Comment: Thanks marcinj! works fine! Any suggestions to improve and learn?

Comment: @greatfullgigapower why do you make `value` a pointer to float, instead of simply having a `float`? When you allocate memory (with `new`) you have to remember to deallocate it (with `delete`). The only safe way to deallocate memory is to use RAII idiom, for example in a form of a smart pointers like `unique_ptr`. But remember, when you dont need a pointer, then dont use it. I myself dont remember when was the last time I had to use `new` or `delete` in my production code.

Comment: Originally it was a void * , but to view that its correct I do static_cast... with float * I can view the value stored while debug the code. The purpose is that I will change the float * with a void *. I know that the code could be an eye pain, but im not a professional. Its only for hobby :)